# Graph API Beta - LearningProviders 401

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, beta

I'm trying to use the beta api of LearningProviders described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/graph/api/employeeexperience-list-learningproviders?view=graph-rest-beta

I'm in a tenant with the new viva integration activeted and in teams i can see correctly all the feature.

With an admin account i'm trying to use the API but I only recive 401 Error with the following body when I try to call the api /employeeExperience/learningProviders

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "UnknownError",
        "message": "",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2022-07-29T12:50:14",
            "request-id": "b985f230-5e34-4e95-9c03-4a192b9cd2e2",
            "client-request-id": "b985f230-5e34-4e95-9c03-4a192b9cd2e2"
        }
    }
}
```

I tried both to call the API from the graph explorer (And i've added the correct permission to the Graph Explorer app registration) and also with a new app registration with the correct delegated permission.
I'm not able anyway to get any response.
Anyone facing the issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

thanks for reaching out to us .
Could you please decode your access token in http://jwt.ms/ and make sure you have LearningProvider.Read delegated permission added in your scopes .

please let us know if you have any query,

thanks

permissions - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#delegated-permissions-27

Comment: This for example is the scope of the token acquired with the graph explorer application:

"scp": "User.Read User.ReadBasic.All User.ReadWrite User.ReadWrite.All  LearningContent.Read.All LearningContent.ReadWrite.All LearningProvider.Read LearningProvider.ReadWrite"

The api I'm calling is this one: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/employeeExperience/learningProviders

Comment: Thanks for the update , I also tried to repo the issue from our side and i am also able to repo the same , looks like there is something wrong in backend side , will create a ICM with respective team to fix this , thanks